# How would I free() a dynamically allocated array in a dynamically allocated struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, free

I have written a program to simulate a "queue" data structure — here is the code:

`queue.h` :

```
#ifndef QUEUE
#define QUEUE

typedef struct Q
{
  int *queue;
  int size;
  int elements;
  int end;
  int beg;

} QueueType;

QueueType *Create(int n);

int Insert_end(QueueType *q_ptr, int n);

int Remove_Beg(QueueType *q_ptr);

int Ret_First(QueueType *q_ptr);

int Ret_Last(QueueType *q_ptr);

#endif
```

`queue.c` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "queue.h"

QueueType *Create(int n)
{
    QueueType *ptr = malloc(sizeof(QueueType));
    ptr->queue = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

    ptr->size = n;
    ptr->beg = n-1;
    ptr->end = n-2; 
    ptr->elements = 0;

    return ptr;
}

int Insert_end(QueueType *q_ptr, int n) // inserts data at end of queue
{        
   if (!(q_ptr->elements == q_ptr->size))   // "elements" is number of valid data in the queue, size is the size of the queue.
   {
     if (q_ptr->elements == 0)     // if the queue is empty
     {
        q_ptr->queue[q_ptr->size-1] = n;
        q_ptr->elements++;
     }
     else                           // if the queue is not empty
     {
        q_ptr->queue[q_ptr->end] = n;
        q_ptr->end = q_ptr->end-1;
        q_ptr->elements++;
     }
   }
   else             // if the queue is full
   {
      printf("Queue Full");
   }
}

int Remove_Beg(QueueType *q_ptr)   // removes beginning element of queue
{
    printf("\n");
    for (int *start = &(q_ptr->queue[q_ptr->beg-1]); start >= &(q_ptr->queue[q_ptr->end-1]); start--) 

    *(start+1) = *start;

// goes from start of queue to end and moves values along so the first value gets overwritten eventually (basically pops the first value and moves each value along)
}

int Ret_First(QueueType *q_ptr) // returns first queue value
{
   return q_ptr->queue[q_ptr->beg];
}

int Ret_Last(QueueType *q_ptr) // returns last queue value
{
   return q_ptr->queue[q_ptr->end];
}
```

`main.c` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "queue.h"

int main()
{
    QueueType *ptr = Create(10);

    Insert_end(ptr,2);
    Insert_end(ptr,4);
    Insert_end(ptr,6);
    Insert_end(ptr,8);
    Insert_end(ptr,10);
    Insert_end(ptr,12);
    Insert_end(ptr,14);
    Insert_end(ptr,16);
    Insert_end(ptr,18);
    Insert_end(ptr,20);

    Remove_Beg(ptr);

    free(ptr->queue);
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that after running valgrind to check for memory leaks and errors, there was still 40 bytes left :

```
==4007== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4007==    definitely lost: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==4007==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4007==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4007==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4007==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

And I can only assume this is from the array of 10 ints that were allocated using the `Create()` function. The main function gives an error from `free()`, so how can I free the array allocated as well as the actual struct the array is stored in?

Comment: You should be able to get more information about the lost memory — either extra options to Valgrind or recompile and relink your code with the `-g` option and run Valgrind again.  If 'extra options' is appropriate, it will suggest the right options to use.

Comment: Your `Remove_Beg()` function is declared to return an `int` but doesn't return anything.  Redefine and redeclare it to return `void`.  However, that doesn't affect the memory leak.

Comment: You _should_ report errors such as `Queue Full` on `stderr` (not `stdout`) and you should terminate messages with a newline: `fprintf(stderr, "Queue Full\n");`.

Comment: Thanks for these helpful suggestions i appreciate it @JonathanLeffler anything else you would suggest to make my code better?

Comment: Do you get any other warnings from Valgrind?  What happens if you remove the `Remove_Beg()` call?  Any or all of the `Insert_end()` calls?  (For consistency, shouldn't `Insert_end()` be renamed `Insert_End()` to match `Remove_Beg()`, `Ret_First()`, `Ret_Last()`?  Consistency in programming is a very important attribute of good code.  It's also very hard to achieve!)

Comment: When I run a minimally adapted version of your code (`Insert_end()` doesn't return a value either), I get 2 "Invalid read of size 4" messages and 1 "Invalid write of size 4" message from `Remove_Beg()` — but no memory leak.  However, that simply means that the undefined behaviour manifests itself differently.  You should look hard at the code in `Remove_Beg()`.  I don't entirely understand what you are doing there, so I can't advise you on how to fix it.  But memory abuse problems need to be fixed more urgently than memory leaks (though memory leaks also need to be fixed).

Comment: `*(start+1) = *start;` is the body of the for loop, but it looks like a single statement. Confused me for a while. Always use braces.

Comment: As @JonathanLeffler said, use `cc -g` to make sure debug info is in the executable.  Then run valgrind this way: `valgrind --leak-check=full  --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes `

Comment: If you are trying to implement a circular buffer queue, then it looks like you don't fully understand how it is supposed to work. In particular, there should be **no** loop in `Remove_Beg`. If you are trying to implement the kind of queue that moves elements around, then it is not clear why you need both `beg` and `end`. In any case, there is a buffer overflow in `Remove_Beg`, you can catch it with `-fsanitize-address` if you want, but I recommend studying your chosen data structure first.